# Are there any UI for MAME?

Tags: games

I used to install GXMAME for launching the MAME games in Ubuntu, but after installing Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) the package does not seem to be available in the Software System. I have tried Gnome Video Arcade, but it simply does not seem to work. Is there another UI that I can use to launch the MAME games?

Comment: There are a few. I would go for sdlmame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [GMAMEUI](http://gmameui.sourceforge.net/) ?

It's a fork of the defunct GXMame project.

[image: GMAMEUI - Main Window]

Comment: That's exactly the tool that I wanted to use! I couldn't install it in Precise using the software center, but now I have downloaded it from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/gmameui/0.2.12-1ubuntu1, and it works. Thanks!