# How to run neogeo games

Tags: emulation

I have some old neo geo games' backups which I play when I was a child. Is there any way of playing this on this ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 6):

There are ancient Neo Geo emulators roaming around. Alongside GnGeo, there is [NeoCD/SDL](http://pacifi3d.retrogames.com/neocdsdl/). I've no idea how well that works but it's just as old so it's just as likely to explode.

The reason NeoGeo gets no love is because people just use MAME. MAME handles a wide spectrum of consoles and arcade machines. And people tend to favour the original arcade ROMs that NeoGeo games are ports of. [UpUbuntu.com has a fairly good tutorial on getting it all set up](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-install-mame-multiple-arcade.html) that I can't beat... But the basics revolve around the `mame` package.

We also have a question about various MAME front-ends:

- [Are there any UI for MAME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148500/are-there-any-ui-for-mame-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

[GnGeo](http://gngeo.berlios.de/) is a neo geo emulator for linux. You may try this one.

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: check the FAQ - http://gngeo.berlios.de/?page=faq

Comment: Doesn't work, it only throws this line: *** buffer overflow detected ***: gngeo terminated

Answer (score 0):

I would give FinalBurn Alpha a try. You can install/use it directly in retroarch:
https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/FinalBurn-Alpha

It supports Neo-Geo specifically.

As noted in another answer most Neo Geo games are ports from arcade games, and you can play the original game i

Answer (score 0):

It difficult to find [Neo Geo Emulators](https://www.retrostic.com/emulators/neo-geo) for Ubuntu but you should try with [RetroArch](https://www.gamulator.com/emulators/new-geo/windows/retroarch) emulator it's usable for all platforms I think so not sure.

Comment: According to the official RetroArch website, *RetroArch can run on the usual platforms like Windows, Mac OS X and Linux*.

Answer (score 0):

[NeoRAGEx](https://www.romspedia.com/emulators/programs/neoragex) is what you are searching for. The emulator is available for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: You've provided the download link for Windows, not Ubuntu. Is there one? Perhaps adding that one would be of extra value over the current one.

Comment: Not sure if there is version for Ubuntu, but you can run it using Wine. The good thing is that with this emulator you have high emulation success rate, while the other emulators I tried can run only like 10% of the games.